# How to pass a selectionArgs when I use the keyword IN in Android?

Tags: android

I hope to use a Args instead of hard code `"_id in ('1','2')"`,

so I write the code `myContext.getContentResolver().delete(uri, "_id in ?", new String[](mListSmsID))`;

I don't know if my code is correct, and how to pass the selectionArgs ? Thanks!

```
public static void DeleteSMS(Context myContext,List<String> mListSmsID){
    Uri uri=PublicParFun.GetUriBySMSRange(SMSRange.All);
    myContext.getContentResolver().delete(uri, "_id in ('1','2')", null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a different ? for each value so it would have to be something like IN (?, ?). Then in your selection args just add the values you want inserted.

```
String selection = "_id in (?, ?, ?)";
String selectionArgs[] = new String[]{"1","2","3"};
```

Comment: Thanks! but I think it's not a good way because sometimes the count of _id is 3 and sometimes the count of _id is 50

Comment: You can construct the selection by using a for loop and concatenate a ? for every arg.